# Best way to randomly spawn stuff indepentently of the users fps

Tags: javascript, random

I wanna spawn randomly each average 2 seconds stuff in my game, independently of the users fps, is this correct then, and if not what's the problem:

```
function update(delta) {
  var interval = 2; // in seconds
  if (Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 / delta) * interval) == 0) spawn();

  ...

  obj.x += obj.vx * delta
}
```

Will this spawn stuff randomly in an average interval of 2 seconds?

Also, is there anyway to do this better?

Comment: What prevents you from testing it yourself?

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Nothing, just wondering what's the laws of randomness

Comment: What is the `delta` supposed to model? If the spawn rate is independent from the delta, then why does delta appear in your function?

Comment: @madshogo Sorry, I didn't mean that, I mean independent of how slow the users computer is.

Comment: @Murplyx Ok. But again, what is the purpose of `delta` here? What do you want its effect to be?

Comment: @madshogo To make sure that it won't be less or more chance to spawn stuff for users who have a slower or faster computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) or [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) should be a good way to ensure that a function is called repeatedly after a certain amount of time.

If you don't want to use that, then have the `update` function of your spawner object use the current world time instead of just the `delta` of the current frame. Also, have the object record the last time it spawned something. This way, you just have to do:

```
// maybe it should be 2000, in milliseconds, idk
if (currentTime - this.lastTimeSomethingSpawned >= 2) {
    spawn();
    this.lastTimeSomethingSpawned = currentTime;
}
```

If you want to randomize the interval instead of having a constant 2 seconds, just recompute a new random interval every time:

```
// maybe it should be 2000, in milliseconds, idk
if (currentTime - this.lastTimeSomethingSpawned >= this.spawningInterval) {
    spawn();
    this.lastTimeSomethingSpawned = currentTime;
    this.spawningInterval = 2 + (2*Math.random()-1)*this.intervalDeviation;
}
```

where `this.intervalDeviation` is something like `0.5`. This way, `this.spawningInterval` will be between 1.5 and 2.5 every time something spawns.

Finally, this question is better suited for the [Gamedev Stackexchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)